# Firebase google cloud function to return a Snapshot

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to return a snapshot like this from a Firebase google cloud function?

```
exports.getFreshData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const ref = data.ref;
  try {
    const snap = await admin.database().ref(ref).once("value");
    return {res: true, snapshot: snap};
  } catch (e) {
    error(e);
    return false;
  }
});
```

When I call this function from my client I get the following error:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at keys (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13333:60)
    at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4920:21
    at baseForOwn (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7)
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:184:18)
    at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13427:38
    at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
    at baseForOwn (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7)
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:184:18)
```

However, if I return `snap.val()` instead, it runs just fine. I want to be able to return the Snapshot though. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable Cloud Functions can only return JSON types, as mentioned in the documentation on [returning a value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result):

> To send data back to the client, return data that can be JSON encoded.

A `DatabaseSnapshot` is not a JSON type, but a more complex JavaScript object. You'll typically want to either return the value of the snapshot, or its key and its value:

```
return { res: true, key: snap.key, value: snap.val() };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to create a DataSnapshot instance from the snap.val() in the client?

Comment: No, you can't create your own `DataSnapshot` instance. The key+value are the same pertinent information though, so you should be able to accomplish the same goals with those two pieces.